Low Solar Panel Voltage Vmp Operation
so I'm currently working on an MPPT project using Asynchronous Buck Converter with the design :

Capacitor Input : 470uF/100V
Capacitor Output : 1000uF/100V
Inductor : 65uH
fsw : 39khz
current : 30A

My solar panel specification:

Voc : 22,11V
Isc : 2,97A
Vmp : 18V
Imp : 2,78A

I'm using 3 solar panels and connect them in parallel to because my battery is 12V VRLA 20Ah, I have 2 and connecting them in parallel, too.
According to the theory of PV Characteristics, Solar Panels only giving a maximum power at 18V.

Then,
I measured the irradiance of sun  using solar power meter, the result is around 850-950 W/m2 which is good

But my solar panels won't produce high current and high voltage to near VMP. The voltage is always drop and the current will never be produced as expected from the specification.
So, whenever my mppt algorithm increase the PWM, the voltage will decrease but the current increases. What I know according to the PV curve, the voltage will remain the same or also increase with pwm & current increase (This situation happen when we are on Left Of MPP Curve).
I Can't get that Vmp 18V with high current, the voltage is always drop when mppt increasing PWM.
Take a look at my arduino serial monitor here,
VI: Voltage Input,
VO: Voltage output,
CI: Current Input,
CO: Current Output
From VOC 21V, drop to 17.8V then ended up to 14V


Last night, my relay didn't cut off the connection between my buck converter and solar panel, so it was like current flow from battery to the solar panels. From my previous testing, the solar panels was giving a nice vmp around 17-18V whenever the mppt algorithm increase the pwm to achieve the maximum of current can be drawn to achieve the MPP. But now, the vmp is too low when mppt increase the pwm and never get that mpp again. 
But I don't see any burn side on my solar panels. 
Also i have checked the voc was 21V at that time, and isc was 4.9A. But on my buck converter, i only can drawn 3.8 A at maximum 97% of my duty cycle and the voltage only around 14.3-15V. Why is this happend? The current is to far from the isc and never reach the vmp 18v...

Adding an actual question is highly desirable. Any ideas you may have on why may help.

How is the MPPT implemented  / controlled? Why does it work on your panel?

I Can't get that Vmp 18V with high current, the voltage is always drop when mppt increasing PWM

@tabun Obviously the voltage of the panel is going to drop when you increase the duty cycle of the PWM - your drawing more current from the panel and that is how buck converters work. For a fixed output voltage, the output current will keep increasing with increasing PWM, until it starts to fall. That's the MPP.

Sorry I forget to mention that last night, my relay didn't cut off the connection between my buck converter and solar panel, so it was like current flow from battery to the solar panels. From my previous testing, the solar panels was giving a nice vmp around 17-18V whenever the mppt algorithm increase the pwm to achieve the maximum of current can be drawn to achieve the MPP. But now, the vmp is too low when mppt increase the pwm and never get that mpp again.

But I don't see any burn side on my solar panels.

More story, this are my new solar panels that installed in this project, before was good until my cut off relay didn't working to cut connection when the solar panel voltage lower than my battery.

@tabun please do not write information in comments ... this site is not a forum ... edit the question and add the info there

okay done. thank you for advice
